# Orc not faster than csv in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I'm fairly new to using Hadoop in production. I used scoop to bring in a large table from a database into Hive. Scoop created a comma delimited text file and created the corresponding table in Hive.

I then executed a `create table new_table_orc stored as orc as select * from old_table_csv`

Since a text file is as about as inefficient as can be compared to ORC (binary data, column wise data storage for fat tables, compression, etc.), I expected a huge, orders of magnitude improvement but the query execution time doesn't seem to have changed at all!

I used the same simple query on both version (text, ORC and even parquet) and did the same thin when several of these tables were used in a join.

Additional info:
The main table I'm testing has around 430 million rows and around 50 columns.

I'm running a couple of queries:
`select sum(col1) from my_table;` <= 40 sec

`select sum(col1) from my_table_orc;` <= 31 sec

And

`select distinct col2 from my_table where col3 = someval;` <= 53 sec

`select distinct col2 from my_table_orc where col3 = someval;` <= 35 sec

I also enabled vectorization, as @sahil desai suggested but does seem to have made a huge different (it did reduce the time by a couple of seconds).

What is going on here, why am I not seeing orders of magnitude speedup? What more detail do you need?

Comment: What query did you run? ORC or Parquet is faster, but not for scanning the whole table

Comment: how big data you have and what are the query you are running matters .If you are testing small data set  you will not able to find any performance diffrence.

Comment: @sandeeprawat Added more info in the description. Data isn't small, although I'm still thinking from the perspective of a single machine.

Comment: @cricket_007 in one of the queries I'm doing a full scan, but only for 1 out of 50 columns, that, alone, should give me a huge speedup.

Comment: What order of magnitude are you expecting? Millions of rows says nothing about the size of the data. Hadoop doesn't like small files either. Just the startup of any mapreduce process is a few seconds. Enable Tez, or switch to SparkSQL, Impala, Presto, Drill, etc to get your queries to run in single seconds.

Answer (score 2):

As per my experience ORC is faster. Using ORC File for every HIVE table should  extremely beneficial to get fast response times for your HIVE queries. I think you have to enable the vectorization, Vectorized query execution improves performance of operations like scans, aggregations, filters and joins, by performing them in batches of 1024 rows at once instead of single row each time.

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;    
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

there are many ways to improve the hive performance like Tez execution, cost based query optimization(CBO) etc.

Comment: I executed your flags in the JDBC client without error. However, the performance seems to have remained the same.